# Varying permissions on Windows Server based on method of authenticating

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, cygwin

I'm running into a weird issue here. 
I have a Windows server setup to allow SSH access via Cygwin.
The idea behind this is to allow me to remotely execute Powershell commands from one of my Linux boxes. Now, in the hopes of being secure while still allowing for automation, I did your typical ssh-copy-id to my designated account on that box. I then tried logging in via SSH keys... success! Now here's the weird part. I run my Powershell command:

```
powershell  'C:/cygwin64/scripts/add_email_address_to_distribution_list.ps1'
```

And get the following error message:

> $ powershell 
>   'C:/cygwin64/scripts/add_email_address_to_distribution_list.ps1' 
>   Add-DistributionGroupMember : Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   serverSettings At
>   C:\cygwin64\scripts\add_email_address_to_distribution_list.ps1:2
>   char:28
>   + Add-DistributionGroupMember <<<<  -Identity **some_distribution_list** -Member **user@ domain.com**
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], 
>       ArgumentNullException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException,Microsoft.Exchange.
>   Management.RecipientTasks.AddDistributionGroupMember

Now if I remove the pubkey from my account's .authorized_keys file, login with my usual password, and retry... the script works!

I'm stumped as to why authentication via password over SSH allows for the script to run successfully , while authentication via keys over SSH doesn't.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here's the script that's being run:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity some_distribution_list -Member user@domain.com
```

Comment: What does your script look like? It's possible that your user account that Cygwin / SSH is running under does not have permission to access a resource earlier in the script, that feeds the `Add-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet. I have no idea how Cygwin works from a user token perspective.

Comment: That's a good thought, but I upped them to admin (just to test quickly and revert afterwards) and the issue still persisted.

Comment: Possible delegation issue?  Updating a DL means connecting to a DC and updating a group membership in 
AD